# how to concatenate the contents of all files in a directory by name order?

Tags: powershell, concatenation

I have a bunch of text files that I need to concatenate into 1 string:

[image]

The end result is a concatenation of the contents of `20211026_113900.sql + 20211027_083900.sql + 20211027_093900.sql`

**How do we concatenate the contents of files ensuring alphabetical order?**

**20211026_113900.sql**

> select name from mytable1 GO

**20211027_083900.sql**

> select name from mytable2 GO

**20211027_093900.sql**

> select name from mytable3 GO

The end result I am expecting is:

> select name from mytable1 GO select name from mytable2 GO select name
> from mytable3 GO

Answer (score 5):

Enumerate all the files with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path path\to\Scripts -File -Filter *.sql
```

The file system provider already returns them in sorted order, but you can explicitly sort them by name using `Sort-Object` for good measure if it makes you more comfortable:

```
$files = $files |Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Finally use `Get-Content -Raw` to read the file contents into memory, and use the `-join` operator to join them:

```
$concatenated = @(
    $files |Get-Content -Raw
) -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

`$concatenated` now contains a single multi-line string with the contents of all the `*.sql` files separated by newlines

Replace `[Environment]::NewLine` with `' '` to concatenate them on the same line as the previous file, or use `-join` in unary mode:

```
$concatenated = -join @(
    $files |Get-Content -Raw
)
```

Comment: Nicely done ("if it makes you more comfortable" is a nice touch :). As for the unary `-join` solution / joining with a newline: Given that `-Raw` returns a file's trailing newline as well, and that text files _typically_ have a trailing newline, the unary `-join` will likely result in _no_ content on the same line, and, conversely, joining with a newline will likely result in an empty line between the content of the respective files. Something like `($files |Get-Content -Raw).TrimEnd("\`r\`n") -join [Environment]::NewLine` would result in predictable separation.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Are you using `@(...)` for conceptual reasons, so as to make it clear that the LHS of `-join` is an _array_? (`-join` accepts a scalar LHS as well, appropriately resulting in a no-op).

Comment: @mklement0 This is simply another case of me trying to subtly express intent - I have to create a subexpression _anyway_ (lest I want to store the file contents in a variable), and the choice of `@(...)` seems appropriate here - it signals we're doing `-join` because we _expect_ a multitude of files :)